# Azure : Custom VM blocked on "provisioning" state

Tags: azure, block, rdp

I created a custom Windows 10 VM on my local PC, converted it in .VHD format then uploaded it on Azure using Azure Powershell.
After that, I created an image using the VHD file on Azure cloud, but when I try to launch a VM created with my custom vm's image on Azure, it stays in "starting (provisioning)" state and I can't reach the remote VM by RDP or ping the VM's IP...
How can I solve this problem?

I have no firewall and no Antivirus.

Comment: Instead of creating VM from the image, can you try create an OS disk from the VHD you uploaded and then create VM from the OS disk.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try this today!

Answer (score 0):

Without technical support which is the important option here, you should start from the [VM access troubleshooting guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-troubleshoot-rdp-connection/). Likely, your VM was stucked because of the misconfiguration. I encountered that issue because of one of three reasons:

1) There was a problem in the datacenter (that happens). To re-deploy the custom VM is the solution. Maybe even in the different region.

2) I made a mistake when i did the sysprep and my server launched after i did my sysprep. So, check if that is the issue. The server should be sysprepped again.

3) Awhile ago, i tried to do that with the domain controller and it did not work. As i understood, it was not suppose to work.

4) UPD. As i missed that you are trying to deploy Windows 10, please be aware that client VM in the cloud is tricky. As i see in the Images Gallery, there is only one Windows 10 **Enterprise** version. See that [article](http://joshheffner.com/how-to-upload-and-run-a-windows-10-enterprise-vm-in-azure/) - it is already supported, but it seems like you should check if you are uploading the Enterprise version.

Please check if you did everything exactly as [official documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/) states.

Comment: I tried to redeploy the custom VM 3 times, I tried to re-create a custom VM with correct Sysprep options so... I don't know what to do...

Comment: @Rhood check my upd answer. Do you try to upload Windows 10 Enterprise or different edition?

Comment: It's a Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Hm. Is it fixed VHD? Do you see anything in the troubleshooting console on the VM dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

If the state is "starting (provisioning)", it means the VM has been created and started on the Hyper-V host, but the guest agent has not notified the health state to the platform yet.  At this moment, the platform (or fabric controller) does not know if the guest OS receives DHCP offer and finishes boot process or not.  Ensure DHCP is turned on, firewall is configured properly, VHD is sysprepped, better to have guest agent installed (optional), then follow the official document and retry the deployment (stop and start VM on the portal).  If it still does not work, file a support ticket.  You may read [How Does VM Boot Up in Azure](http://imperfect.work/2016/05/15/azure-vm-boot/) to understand the technical details.